# Count number of duplicates within each group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, pandas-groupby

Suppose I have a DF

```
DF1:
IDField | Frame | Order
--------|-------|------
   20   | 10_01 |   0
   20   | 10_01 |   0
   20   | 10_01 |   1
   20   | 10_02 |   2
   5    | 02_01 |   0
   5    | 02_01 |   1
```

I want to find how many times `IDField` `20` in `Frame` `10_01` has duplicates in `Order`. In this example, `Order` is duplicated once. I'm not concerned with anything that is not a duplicate. I'd like my final output to look like this:

```
DF2:
IDField | Frame | Order | Duplicates
--------|-------|-------|-----------
   20   | 10_01 |   0   |     1
```

I've tried grouping by and counting like so:

```
df2 = df1.groupby(['IDField', 'Frame', 'Order']).size().reset_index(name='Duplicates')
```

While this does give me a duplicate count, it gives me a count for everything, not just the duplicates. Is there an elegant way to one line this? Or do I have to create a `dataframe` and process it afterwards?

Comment: What about IDField 5?

Comment: @coldspeed Since there aren't any duplicates of `Order`, I don't want it displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need an initial filtering step with `duplicated`, then you can group on the columns and compute the `size`:

```
c = ['IDField', 'Frame', 'Order']
df[df.duplicated(c)].groupby(c).size().reset_index(name='Duplicates')

   IDField  Frame  Order  Duplicates
0       20  10_01      0           1
```

---

```
c = ['IDField', 'Order']
df[df.duplicated(c)].groupby(c).size().reset_index(name='Duplicates')

   IDField  Order  Duplicates
0       20      0           1
```

Comment: Going back, how could I ignore the `Frame` entirely and show just that `IDField` `20` has 1 duplicate?

Comment: @AGH_TORN Use `u = df[df.duplicated(['IDField', 'Order'])]`, and I think the rest should remain the same.